# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: java, flutter, dart, gradle

So I have been looking everywhere on the internet for this error but I couldn't find any solutions for it.

I have tried nearly everything:

- Reinstalling android studio
- Reinstalling flutter/dart
- Reinstalling java (and changing java Paths)
- Trying different versions of Gradle
- Trying different min/target sdk versions

So after a 2 days of trying I decided to reach out to you guys, and ask if you have any solutions for it:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    > Failed to query the value of task ':app:processDebugManifest' property 'mainMergedManifest'.
    Could not create task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general errors with many possibilities. However it all comes down to how you are config your Android app. I encountered these kinds of issue mostly when integrating Firebase with my app.

For this case, you could try do the following steps to make sure you got the right config:

- Check your build.gradle to include all necessary repositories and dependencies. Eg: `google()`, `maven()`, etc. Or `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`
- Check your app/build.gradle to include all necessary dependencies. For example: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0` if you use Map API from Google SDK
- Open the Android project within your Flutter app with Android Studio and check the more detail errors come up when running build if any (and update in your questions for further supports)
- After all steps, run `Flutter clean` and rebuild the app
- If everything seems really hard to debug, personally I stop wasting too much time by creating a new Flutter project, copy my /lib, /assets/ and pubspec.yaml from my current project, and start config the app step by step again to avoid running into any random bug without knowing which might cause it.